# Appium Scripts are failed to Execute while setting AUTOMATION_NAME = "ESPRESSO"

Tags: appium, android-espresso, appium-android

I am using Espresso Driver to run my script. Every time it asks me to do the instrumentation. But I don't have the source code, since I only received the .APK file from my customer. In this case, is there any workaround?

The version, code, and log details are below.

```
Appium Version : Appium 1.14.0 - Beta 1 (Tested with Appium 1.13 also)


dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ESPRESSO);
dc.setCapability("forceEspressoRebuild", "true");
dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.example.android.contactmanager");
dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.example.android.contactmanager.ContactManager");
```

I have used `dc.setCapability("forceEspressoRebuild", "true");`

```
Error Stack Trace "Exception in thread "main" 
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. 
Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{io.appium.espressoserver.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=13612, uid=13612 not allowed because package io.appium.espressoserver.test does not have a signature matching the target com.phonepe.app
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'INBLR-JENAB', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup) **needs to be** in the application, you're trying to test using the [appium-espresso-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-espresso-driver). Check out [How to Get Started with Espresso (Android)](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/getting_started_espresso/) article to get familiarized with the concept.

If it is not there and you don't have access to the sources - you won't be able to use the Espresso driver, you will have to go for [UIAutomator2](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/) instead

Answer (score 0):

I did not use Epresso like you, but had a similar problem. The issue is you have to sign apk lib to match with your device. Sometimes your device is special and it requires special signature.

Here what I did:

1. Find apk of ui2automoator, I found them here  (C:\Users\duy.chung\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks)

   2. Sign them
   3. Put apks signed back to the original folder

So I guess you can do the same thing by finding appium-espresso-driver apk and sign them, then put them back to the original folders of node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is off-late as I am starting with Appium with Espresso presently, I was able to solve this issue by wiping the data from the Android emulator in Android Studio AVD Manager and then running the Espresso test. And the signature issue was resolved. But the problem is after clearing the data, the emulator on restart takes a lot of time.